# Display a custom field under WooCommerce single product image

Tags: woocommerce

I am trying to display a custom field on Woocommerce single product page just under the product image.
Does anyone know the hook for this custom field?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above by adding in follows hook -

```
function add_custom_field_just_under_image(){
    global $product;
    echo "Your custom code goes here";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'add_custom_field_just_under_image', 10 );
```

Codes goes to active theme's functions.php